# Using Jquery inject data to my plain html file from node.js , seems like not working on client side, but my console is working

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

Mostly from internet's online, node.js user when they try to implement or inject data from node to
client side (.html) is using jade framework, what if i didn't use jade framework, i need use plain html and i need inject my own data using jQuery in node.js? like,jquery's append(),html() function?
Below is my code trying to use html to change client site's html, console is updated, but when i go to my
web page, is still show me the old text 'yo' instead updated text 'new-text'.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3700;
var jsdom = require('jsdom')


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    var env = require('jsdom').env;

    env('./index.html', function (errors, window) {
        var $ = require('jquery')(window);
        console.log($('#header').text());
        $('#header').html('new-text');
        console.log($('#header').text());
    });

    res.sendfile('./index.html');

});

app.listen(port);
```

And here is the plain html that I'm using

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
<h1 id="header">yo</h1>
<p id="paragraph">lorem</p>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not aware of jsdom but are you sure it will modify the index.html file? Because in the end, you are sending index.html content as response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is not doing what you think it is doing, because:

1. `jsdom` won't modify your `./index.html` file.
2. Even if `jsdom` did modify your file, `jsdom.env` is asynchronous so you'd still be sending the file from before the change.

What you could do is change your code to send a serialized version of the DOM you modified. The following code changes the text and serves it to the client:

```
env('./index.html', function (errors, window) {
    var $ = require('jquery')(window);
    $('#header').html('new-text');
    res.write($("html")[0].outerHTML);
    res.end();
});
```

Note that the code above is meant to illustrate what a solution could look like. It is not meant to be used as-is in production.

A final note: using jsdom and jQuery to perform the task you are doing seems extremely "heavy" to me. A templating system which is designed for generating templates on the fly for the purpose of producing HTTP responses would most likely be faster than using jsdom + jQuery.